# CSS - Slide Loop

Tags: css, loops, slide

```
   background: #ececec url(images/x/x.jpg) top left repeat-x;
```

I want to slide it. It's loopy image. I want to slide it from left to right or right to left. It doesen't matter... How can I do this?

Comment: Please take some time to look into css animations and let us know if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using keyframes, here's a good example;
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `animation` to `background` then you can use pseudo element and add `animation` to it

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:-1;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/200x200) no-repeat;
  -webkit-animation: slide 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: slide 4s linear infinite;
  animation: slide 4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 101%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -101%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 101%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -101%;
  }
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 101%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -101%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <p>The background image is moving</p>
</div>
```